# Jquery Replace all element not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem in my project. I want to replace `&gt;` to ». I used this jquery to change it. But only one element is changing. Second one is not change.
This is HTML:

```
<div id="breadcrumbs"><a href="#" class="home">Home</a> &gt; <a href="#">Second-page</a> &gt; Third-page</div>
```

This is jquery:

```
jQuery("#breadcrumbs").html(jQuery("#breadcrumbs").html().replace('&gt;', '»'));
```

Thanks.

Comment: And in my opinion is better to use css pseudo-elements like :after and :before, and remove from markup &gt; simbols

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery("#breadcrumbs").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).html(jQuery(".breadcrumbs").html().replace('&gt;', '»'));
})
```

I think this will help , small remark: don't put more that one ID on page, use classes inside.

Comment: Thanks. Not working.